# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" but can console log result completely fine?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have two pieces of state currently. One is an empty array called "subproducts", the other is called "additionalprod".

subproducts is an array which pulls information from my backend database using Axios. It is mounted inside of a componentDidMount for the API call.

additionalprod(uct) is a piece of state that gets its value from a prop from a parent, it is a number, in this case for my testing purposes, the number is 5. Number 5 links to a small array containing 3 properties. Product, img_url and id.

When I console.log the exact code

```
console.log(this.state.subproducts[5])
```

I get the response I want, that specific array, so I am 100% targeting it correctly. It currently has 2 arrays inside of it with their own props.
[image]

However, when I try and map through that state, using the code

```
{this.state.subproducts[5].map((product) => {
<h1>{product.img_url}</h1>
})}
```

I get the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

Anybody know whats wrong?

Code in question:

```
import React from "react"
import axios from "axios"

class SubProducts extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      subproducts: [],
      stage: "3",
      selected: this.props.selected,
      additionalprod: this.props.additionalprod,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("http://localhost/api/subproducts.php").then((res) => {
      this.setState({ subproducts: res.data })
      console.log(this.state.subproducts[5])
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.subproducts[this.state.additionalprod].map((product) => {
          ;<h1>{product.img_url}</h1>
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default SubProducts
```

**EDIT:**

After using Sean Rileys fix, I am trying to console log {product} by itself and now I am being hit with this in the console, still can't get it to output though by putting {product.img_url}, there is an error, 'Failed to compile'

[image]

Comment: you dont want to set a state in the component for `selected` and `additionalprod`, when the prop is a state itself from the parent component

Comment: your problem is that `state.additonalprod` never updates. When your parent component is handling it already you can use `this.state.subproducts[this.props.additionalprod]`

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait for a response before render, just add checking on length for your array:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({additionalprod: this.props.additionalprod}, () => {
    axios.get("http://localhost/api/subproducts.php").then((res) => {
      this.setState({ subproducts: res.data })
      console.log(this.state.subproducts[5])
    });
 }
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.subproducts.length > 0 ? 
         this.state.subproducts[this.state.additionalprod].map((product) => 
            <h1>{product.img_url}</h1>
          }) : null 
    </div>
  )
 }
```

Comment: just remove extra quotes in the map function

Comment: @DonnieBerry save additionalprod in compenetDidMount

Answer (score 1):

On the initial render, `this.state.subproducts` is empty so it can't run the map function on the array. It is only after the API call that the array is filled with data.

This is a very common React issue which was a very simple solution of checking that the array isn't empty before running the method on it.

```
{this.state.subproducts && this.state.subproducts[this.state.additionalprod].map((product) => {
  <h1>{product.img_url}</h1>
})}
```

`this.state.subproducts &&`... is just checking if the array returns truthy which it will if it isn't empty and then, if so, it will run the next bit of code.

Another option is "optional chaining" which pretty much does the same thing.

```
{this.state.subproducts[this.state.additionalprod]?.map((product) => {
  <h1>{product.img_url}</h1>
})}
```

Notice the question mark right before `map` `?.map`. By adding the question mark after the array that we're calling the function on, it will only run if the array is defined otherwise it will return `undefined` but you won't get an error.

Comment: hmmm, still no output! Using the second method, there is no error but there is also no output on the front end?

Comment: However, if I do <h1>{console.log({ product })}</h1>, it logs it to console! 

<h1>{console.log({ product.img_url })}</h1> wont work tho

Comment: @DonnieBerry are you sure that `this.state.additionalprod` is the desired value?

Comment: Yes, I even tried just '5' instead of 'this.state.additionalprod', that will pull from my database everything with the ID of 5. It works, but it just wont log, I'll post a screenshot as an update